# Frame offset in xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, frame, cgrect

How do I write the following Swift 4 code in Xamarin C#

```
    viewToMove.Frame = viewToMove.Frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: movement);
```

I have tried:

```
    viewToMove.Frame.Offset(0, movement);
```

But it doesn't do anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just recrate the Frame, `ViewToMove.Frame = new CGRect(viewToMove.x, viewToMove.y + movement, viewToMove.Frame.Width, viewToMove.Frame.Height);` Sorry for the short answer but that's really all you should need to do.